# Default WebView for Xamarin Forms iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm trying to migrate from using UIWebView to WKWebView for Xamarin Forms iOS but I have a few questions because this all seems to be pretty new and none of the resources are helping me online.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/7367

I came across this link though, and apparently the WKWebview is not the default for Xamarin.Forms for 4.0+ and so,

1) I'm currently using Xamarin Forms 3.4.0.x. From my understanding, is all I have to do to get the WKWebView upgrading to 4.4.0.991477, the latest build?

2) Follow up to question 1, how would I not change any code because my cs files contain "using UIKit", which is the namespace for UIWebView, is it not?

3) In this link, it seems like there is no design change at all.. but I thought that WKWebView contained a URL link at the top of the page, which UIWebView does not, which is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have only cross-platform code, then yes there is nothing that you need to worry about, it just works.

2) As you suggest that you have UIKit in your code, then obviously that won't work. UIKit is not Xamarin.Forms API and basically you don't use Xamarin.Forms in this case, but rather Xamarin.iOS.

3) Neither of those controls display URL.

Comment: Thanks! For 3) then, how can I tell if my code worked and I have the WKWebView now?

Comment: @chung if it works it works if it doesn’t it doesn’t that should be obvious

Comment: I meant I don't know what the difference is visually between the two WebViews. I just upgraded my Xamarin Forms and the code runs, but if there is no difference between the interface, how can I tell the Views changed? I'm working with a huge project and I'm not actually 100% sure if I have cross-platform or native for this section or not, so I want to see if the update automatically changed the view

Comment: After XF 4.4.x , WebView in iOS platform had used `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView` in default(Which contains in WebKit) .